# Проблема с кнопками Python в telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я пытаюсь написать бота для магазина в телеграмме, создал клавиатуру из четырех кнопок и расписал какое действие нужно выполнить при нажатии ''купить'', но по какой-то причине бот просто выводит три строчки текста (как в целом и должно быть), но не запоминает ответ пользователя, если пытаться ответить боту что-то два и более раз, то программа вообще ломается. Как нужно написать этот промежуток кода, чтобы бот задал вопрос - запомнил ответ - задал следующий вопрос и эта схема работала любое количество раз?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
        if message.text == "Купить":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какой товар хотите купить?")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, basket)
            def reg_basket(message):
                global basket
                basket = message.text
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Как вас зовут?")
                bot.register_next_step_handler(message, name)
            def reg_name(message):
                global name
                name = message.text
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Какой у вас номер телефона?")
                bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number)

        def reg_number(message):
            global number
            # age = message.text
            while number == 0:
                try:
                    number = int(message.text)
                except Exception:
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вводите цифрами!")

        reg_basket(message)
        reg_name(message)
        reg_number(message)


    elif message.text == 'О нас':

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо", callback_data='good')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не очень", callback_data='bad')

        markup.add(item1, item2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично, сам как?', reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'иди в жопу ')
```

Comment: уже было и не раз ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209804/234134

Answer (score 0):

Надо написать `msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какой товар хотите купить?")` и в register_next_step_handler передавать msg.